# Degree of Equations

Tags: functions, polynomials

> A) Which variables in the formula $V = \pi r^2 h$ would you need to set as a constant in order to generate:
>
> 1. a linear equation?
> 2. a quadratic equation?
>
> B) How should $r$ and $h$ be related to generate a cubic function?

Please help me understand the above question.

Comment: 1) r, 2) h 3) linearly.

Comment: I get 1 and 2 now, but I'm still confused as to how a liner function can generate a cubic one when r isn't at the third power, or degree 3.

Comment: Let $h = ar$ for some $a > 0$

Comment: So---> V= πr^2(5r) = 15.7r^3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first part,

A.

> **1)** To obtain a linear equation the [degree of polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial) (**I think you should check the link first**) should be equal to 1. Hence in your equation $V=\pi r^2h$ if we consider $h$ as a variable and $r$ as a constant then we can obtain a polynomial which is having degree 1 (as $r$ in the given equation will be a constant hence $r^2$ will not make any difference at all) resulting your equation to be linear.
>
> Hence answer is $r$ should be a constant
>
> **2)** Similarly to obtain a quadratic polynomial (i.e. degree of polynomial is 2) will have to make $h$ a constant so that $r$ can be a variable with power 2. Hence the polynomial will be quadratic.
>
> Hence answer is $h$ should be constant.

---

For your second part

B.

> You will need any kind of linear relation between h and r. For example $h=\theta r$ where $\theta$ is a fixed constant. From this you can rewrite your equation from
>
> $$V=\pi r^2h$$
>
> to
>
> $$V=\pi r^2(\theta r)$$
> $$V=\pi \theta r^3$$
>
> And this is how you'll obtain a cubic equation.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was informative and easy to understand.